# Is there a way to set the default database handle with mysql_query?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to set the default database handle with mysql_query? So I know that mysql_query can be called without a sql handle but then it will basically use whatever handle you got from the **last** mysql_connect. What if I wanted to set that default handle myself, how do I do it?

---

I just want to make it clear that we have all our code written without the handler passed in. We can't change those. We have some code behind the scenes that changes the database between different database clusters. We want to be able to switch between the database without calling mysql_connect repeatedly.

Comment: Tired of passing around a paramater to a function every single time?  Try [using an object-oriented](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) database interface instead, and get [prepared statements](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) at no extra cost!  Buy now!  (Also, [PDO](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  Seriously, though, please consider using a more modern database interface.)

Comment: I was in a similar delima a while ago, in asp wid mySQl. I asked a ques too, too bad it got few reply. Your ques gave some sort of eureka to solve my problem...thanx.

Answer (score 3):

Super ghetto version.

```
$defaultHandle;

function SetDefaultHandle($handle){
    global $defaultHandle;
    $defaultHandle = $handle;
}

function q($query){
    global $defaultHandle;
    return mysql_query($query,$defaultHandle);
}
```

Comment: +1 for actually providing a usable solution, and calling it out for the hack it is.

Comment: Can you override the mysql_query function? Otherwise this wouldn't work.

Comment: Why wouldn't it?  You'd have to replace all calls to `mysql_query` in your existing codebase with calls to `q` instead, of course.  But you'd have to do that regardless.  **There is no way to make `mysql_query` do what you want,** there are only workarounds and hacks.  This is a workaround, and a hackish one at that.  But, it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide the connection you can pass it in the function call as the second argument. See [documentation of `mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for further details.

Comment: We can't we have our code written such that all the query are done without pass in the handles. And then we switch the database behind the scenes between our db farms

Comment: How are you going to generate the link identifier if you don't connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
mysql_query($query, $dbc);
```

From [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> `resource mysql_query ( string $query [, resource` **`$link_identifier ]`** `)`
>
> **`link_identifier`** - The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pointing you at the manual, which you certainly have read by now based off your question...

**You can't do this with the `mysql` extension.**

The magic "pick the last handle opened" behavior is *defined by the extension itself*.  There's nothing you can do to change this behavior.

The behavior you've asked for will require custom code, almost certainly replacing every call to every function with an appropriate wrapper that picks the correct database handle for your load balancing situation.